# error when retrieving out parameter from mysql

Tags: mysql, servlets

I was getting this message when i tried to retrieve out parameter from mysql stored procedure in my servlet. Can you help me to solve it, thanks.

Error Message :

```
Error found: Exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`pIsValid`,@com_mysql_jdbc_outparam_`pMessage`)' at line 1
```

My stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `m_test`(OUT `pIsValid` VARCHAR(50), OUT `pMessage` VARCHAR(50))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
SET pIsValid := 'NO';
set pMessage := 'Hai there';
END
```

My Servlet to call the procedure :

```
strQuery = "{call m_test(?,?)}";
    cs = conMain.prepareCall(strQuery);
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);

    cs.execute();
    isValid = cs.getString(1);
    strAlert = cs.getString(2);
```